# How to Unit Test without Hitting Database

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I want to ask what is a good unit test for the method below **GetMeetingsByInterimIdentifier** where interim identifier is a string -- such as 78th2015.

We are setup to use the interface IMeetingsService.  We are using MOQ and Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.

```
public class MeetingsService : IMeetingsService
{
    private readonly IInterimCommitteeDbContext _db;

    public MeetingsService(IInterimCommitteeDbContext db)
    {
        this._db = db;
    }

    public IQueryable<Meeting> GetMeetingsByInterimIdentifier(string interimIdentifier)
    {
        return
            from m in this._db.Meetings
            join c in this._db.Committees on m.CommitteeId equals c.CommitteeId
            where c.InterimIdentifier == interimIdentifier
            select m;
    }

    public Meeting GetMeeting(int meetingKey)
    {
        return this._db.Meetings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.MeetingId == meetingKey);

    }

}
```

**Edit:**

But I am not sure how to set it up. This result is not null, but what does it do for me?

```
[TestMethod] 
public void GetMeetingsByInterimIdentifier_WithInterimIdentifier_ReturnsMeetingList() 
{ 
    //Arrange 
    var interim = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultInterimIdentifier; 
    var result = _meetingServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetMeetingsByInterimIdentifier(interim)); 

    //Act 

    //Assert 
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

Comment: I probably wouldn't bother unit testing this. You're testing that database objects are returned from EF based on a filter (`interimIdentifier`). Your code doesn't manipulate the result after the LINQ statement executes, so you'd be better off creating an integration test that actually hits the database.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Mock<IInterimCommitteeDbContext>` and pass it into the constructor. On this object setup the `Meetings` and `Committees` properties to return various collections.

You should have different tests setup that return different collections. For example, how should this behave if both the `Meetings` and `Committees` are empty, i.e. there is no data in the database? How should it behave if there isn't an object with the provided `InterimIdentifier`? What about if there is one that matches etc.

Comment: But I am not sure how to even set it up.  This does not work:

Comment: Maybe add what you have so far to the question or create a new question with what you have got?

Comment: But I am not sure how to set it up.  This result is not null, but what does it do for me?
[TestMethod]
public void GetMeetingsByInterimIdentifier_WithInterimIdentifier_ReturnsMeetingList()
        {
            //Arrange
            var interim = Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultInterimIdentifier;
            var result = _meetingServiceMock.Setup(x => x.GetMeetingsByInterimIdentifier(interim));

            //Act

            //Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result); 

        }

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this using test doubles.  I am using Entity Framework 6 with the code first model.  I created a DbContext that inherited from my I-DbContext interface.  Then I was able to create in-memory data to use in my service layer unit tests.  Below is an example of:

1. the test data context,
2. the test dbset,
3. an example unit test.

This solution was available from an msdn article here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn314429.aspx
...

```
        public class CommitteeContextTest : ICommitteeDbContext
        {
            public CommitteeContextTest()
            {
                this.Committees = new TestDbSet();
                this.CommitteeMembers = new TestDbSet();
            }
            public Database Database { get; }
            public DbSet Committees { get; set; }
            public DbSet CommitteeMembers { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

```
public class TestDbSet : DbSet, IQueryable, IEnumerable, IDbAsyncEnumerable
            where TEntity : class
    {
        ObservableCollection _data;
        IQueryable _query;

        public TestDbSet()
        {
            _data = new ObservableCollection();
            _query = _data.AsQueryable();
        }

        public override TEntity Add(TEntity item)
        {
            _data.Add(item);
            return item;
        }

        public override TEntity Remove(TEntity item)
        {
            _data.Remove(item);
            return item;
        }

        public override TEntity Attach(TEntity item)
        {
            _data.Add(item);
            return item;
        }

        public override TEntity Create()
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance();
        }
    }

    [TestClass]
    public class CommitteeServiceTest
    {
        private InterimCommitteeContextTest _interimCommitteeContext;
        private ICommitteeService _service;
        private string _interim;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            _interimCommitteeContext = new InterimCommitteeContextTest();
            _service = new CommitteeService(_interimCommitteeContext);
            _interim = Settings.Default.DefaultInterimIdentifier;
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            _interimCommitteeContext = null;
            _service = null;
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void GetCommittee_ProvideInterimCommitteeId_ReturnOneCommittee()
        {
            //Arrange
            AddCommittees();

            //Act and Assert
            var result = _service.GetCommittee(_interim, 1);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, result.CommitteeId); //Passes.  IsActive set to true;
            result = _service.GetCommittee(_interim, 0);
            Assert.IsNull(result); //Fails.  No committeeId = 0;
            result = _service.GetCommittee(_interim, 2);
            Assert.IsNull(result); //Fails.  CommitteeId = 2 is not active.
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AddCommittees()
        {
            _interimCommitteeContext.Committees.Add(new Committee() { CommitteeId = 1, InterimIdentifier = _interim, IsActive = true, CommitteeTypeId = 1 });
            _interimCommitteeContext.Committees.Add(new Committee() { CommitteeId = 2, InterimIdentifier = _interim, IsActive = false, CommitteeTypeId = 1 });
            _interimCommitteeContext.Committees.Add(new Committee() { CommitteeId = 3, InterimIdentifier = _interim, IsActive = true, CommitteeTypeId = 1 });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use [Mocking](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAAahUKEwiz25fRxojIAhUGnpQKHQWbBx0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FMock_object&usg=AFQjCNEfPJdaa37pZPMjC73KEggdFaYwhA&sig2=OTTUwd9VWAdEM22G6fTAHQ), that's what it is for. Use [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/) or [Mockito](http://mockito.org/) or any other library you prefer.

Comment: It's not an answer, more over; you offer the OP an Irrelevant frameworks since he use `C#` not `Java` and in SO single line is not an answer...